# XMLHttpRequest() does not work probably in a Truffle project

Tags: contract-development, truffle, javascript, nodejs

I want to connect to my smart contract in a Truffle project and get some information from it. The smart contract's name is "TEST". The follow is my app.js code that should communicate with my smart contract:

```
var Web3=require("web3");
var web3= new Web3('ws://localhost:8545');
   web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);
let request=new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET","E:\Emrooz\build\contracts\TEST.json");
    request.send(null);
var jsonFile=JSON.parse(request.responseText);
var myContract=new 
    web3.eth.Contract(jsonFile,"0xC8129A44979263D578A8BD52d403d6537820e969",{ 
    account:"0xeB2a9E0338616e35B5e844Bd38924C79D99d7346", balance:"99.98990494"});
var acc=myContract.defaultAccount;
    console.log(acc.toString());
```

Here, "Emrooz" is name of file of Truffle project. But when i complie app.js with Nodejs the following error occurrs:

[image]

Even, i added `var XMLHttpRequest=require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;` to the code but that error occurrs again. Whats the problem? What should i do?

Comment: Is that me or you try to send an HTTP request to a file ?

Comment: Client-side application

Comment: I don't understand. A file cannot handle a HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest();` is not required to connect with the smart contract and receive information from it. The purpose of the provided code in question is receiving the address that exist in

```
new web3.eth.Contract(…)
```

For that, we can use

```
myContract.options.accoun
```

instead of

```
myContract.defaultAccount
```

The below code is the altered version of the question code that outputs the desirable result:

```
var Web3=require("web3");
var fs=require('fs');//fs module added in solution.
var web3= new Web3('ws://localhost:8545');
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);// shows all accounts exist in the project
var JsonFile=fs.readFileSync("E:/Emrooz/build/contracts/TEST.json");
var JsFile=JSON.parse(JsonFile);
var myContract=new web3.eth.Contract(JsFile.abi," 0xC8129A44979263D578A8BD52d403d6537820e969
",{ account:" 0xeB2a9E0338616e35B5e844Bd38924C79D99d7346
", balance:"99.98990494"});
console.log(myContract.options.account);//shows the desirable result.
```